# rails - administrate + devise creating new users goes to devise controller

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-6, administrate, rails-administrate

I am working on a rails application using rails administrate. I have an admin interface with a resource called `admin_users` that is controlled by devise. Right now, users are really only made in the rails console, and devise was added to allow an omniauth ability on users. On that dashboard, I want an option to create admin_users for additional users I want to invite into the application, as this is easier than doing it from the rails console in production.

I have a controller, `Admin::AdminUsersController` to handle this functionality to match the dashboard. right now, it lists the current admin_users in the system that have been created from the rails console and that works fine.

Now, I am adding the option to create admin users from the rails administrate interface. However, when filling out the form at `admin/admin_users/new`, devise seems to intercept the request and seems like it attempts to log me out. Looking in my rails server, here are the logs

```
app_1  | Started POST "/admin/admin_users" for 192.168.96.1 at 2020-02-25 02:38:41 +0000
app_1  | Cannot render console from 192.168.96.1! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255, ::1
app_1  | Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#create as HTML
app_1  |   Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"LPbT7OCx8upC5ehWIZ1JV/o/UKttciyoThOgi06B4AUw8ve3x/stbjUT7Trvb9u0YMEoyEBobbbni0g7LNWvBg==", "admin_user"=>{"email"=>"test@somemail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "reset_password_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "reset_password_sent_at"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_created_at"=>""}, "commit"=>"Create Admin user"}
app_1  |   AdminUser Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "admin_users".* FROM "admin_users" WHERE "admin_users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "admin_users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", "2d795b9d-2b6f-4745-a58d-775076100c60"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
app_1  | Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
app_1  | Filter chain halted as :require_no_authentication rendered or redirected
app_1  | Completed 302 Found in 6ms (ActiveRecord: 0.6ms | Allocations: 2088)
app_1  | 
app_1  | 
app_1  | Started GET "/" for 192.168.96.1 at 2020-02-25 02:38:41 +0000
app_1  | Cannot render console from 192.168.96.1! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255, ::1
app_1  | Processing by Rails::WelcomeController#index as HTML
app_1  |   Rendering /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-6.0.2.1/lib/rails/templates/rails/welcome/index.html.erb
app_1  |   Rendered /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-6.0.2.1/lib/rails/templates/rails/welcome/index.html.erb (Duration: 3.6ms | Allocations: 201)
app_1  | Completed 200 OK in 6ms (Views: 5.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 1004)
app_1  |
```

And I cannot get the controller to hit my `Admin::AdminUsersController#create` action. Looking at the logs it looks like it hits my post route at `/admin/admin_users`, devise intercepts it at `Devise::RegistrationsController#create`, it gets stopped from `Filter chain halted as :require_no_authentication`, and then redirects to my root route which is similar to when I logout.

I even added a view to override administrate's default views at `app/views/admin/admin_users/new.html.erb` to trigger the form to go to the controller action I'm looking for, like so

```
<section class="main-content__body">
  <%= form_for([namespace, page.resource], :url => url_for(:controller => 'admin/admin_users', :action => 'create'), html: { class: "form" }) do |f| %>
    <% if page.resource.errors.any? %>
      <div id="error_explanation">
        <h2>
          <%= pluralize(page.resource.errors.count, "error") %>
          prohibited this <%= page.resource_name %> from being saved:
        </h2>

        <ul>
          <% page.resource.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
            <li class="flash-error"><%= message %></li>
          <% end %>
        </ul>
      </div>
    <% end %>

    <% page.attributes.each do |attribute| -%>
      <div class="field-unit field-unit--<%= attribute.html_class %>">
        <%= render_field attribute, f: f %>
      </div>
    <% end -%>

    <div class="form-actions">
      <%= f.submit %>
    </div>
  <% end %>

</section>
```

I have also tried adding to my `devise_scope :admin_user` in my routes like

```
devise_scope :admin_user do
  post "/admin/admin_users", to: 'admin/admin_users#create'
end
```

Which didn't do anything.

The functionality I'm looking for is when I am on my admin_users dashboard, to create an admin_user using my `Admin::AdminUsersController#create` action instead of `Devise::RegistrationsController#create` action.

Does anyone know what I need to add to enable this?

Comment: I have created an app as you describe, but haven't been able to reproduce the problem. Questions: what version of Rails are you using? What class does `Admin::AdminUsersController` inherit from? (it should be `Admin::ApplicationController`, and in turn `Administrate::ApplicationController`. If instead you inherit from `Devise::RegistrationsController`, you'll have to replicate the functionality from `Administrate::ApplicationController`). Are you able to provide an repo with a reproduction?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with namespace?

```
namespace :admin do 
  devise_for :users
  # if the above doesn't work 
  # devise_for :admin_users
end
```

In addition you could try overriding the `Administrate` base controller like described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59824297/1737811 with the necessary fields.

Comment: related to that stackoverflow thread you posted, my dashboard for my `admin_user` resource looks exactly like that one, which is puzzling. In my `routes.rb` I have a `devise_for :admin_users, path: 'admin/admin_users'` above my `namespace :admin`. The problem seems to be when I `post` my form, the `post` is being sent to `Devise::RegistrationsController#create` instead of `Admin::AdminUsersController#create`. from adding in routes, to a custom form hitting the URL, etc, devise still seems to be intercepting my post instead of it going to my Admin::AdminUsersController

Comment: Hmm. That's very interesting indeed. But did you try`devise_for :admin_users, controllers: {registrations: 'admin/admin_users/registrations`}` as described on their wiki: https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/wiki/Tool:-Generate-and-customize-controllers

Comment: adding `controllers: { registrations: 'admin/admin_users' }` to my `devise_for :admin_users` in my `routes.rb` worked for me. thanks!